# Jquery $.post issues

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I'm using Jquery to process a form without loading a new page. I'm getting as far as being able to get an alert with the email address placed in the input field 'mailingfield'.
I cant work out why post isn't working (more directly, the image doesn't do anything onclick.
the .mailbutton is an image.

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    $(".mailbutton").click(function() {
        var email = $(".mailingfield").val();
        $.post("/localhost/PHP_scripts/mailinglist.php", {
            email: email
        }, function(data) {
            var content = $(data).find('#content');
            $("#box").empty().append(content);
        }
        });
    };
```

the mailinglist.php is looking for "email" to be set by $_POST.
It then validates for security etc then if the email address pass the validations it's inserted into a database then the code parses a block of html preceeded with a div ID'd content. If the validations fail it produces a similar block of html preceeded with the content div, with a relevant warning.
Am i going about this the right way.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a bunch of syntax errors with this code

Comment: I didn't correct the syntax. I just added some indentation to make it readable

Comment: sorry, so new i can't even put the right comment in the right box. thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest binding the event to the button in the document ready block like this (Not to mention I fixed your syntax errors. As long as the url is correct this will work):

<s>window.onload = init;</s>

```
$(function(){

   $(".mailbutton").click(function() {
      var email = $(".mailingfield").val();
      $.post("/localhost/PHP_scripts/mailinglist.php", { email: email }, function(data) {
            var content = $(data).find('#content');
            $("#box").empty().append(content);
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in the NET tab of the firefox with firebug and see if the request is being sent on click and if using chrome check the netowrk tab to see on click whether any request is getting generated..

are you sure your post url is correct....

it means that if your website is http://www.example.com/
and your page from which yu are sending ajax request is http://www.example.com/makeajaxcall/ajaxrequest.php then your ajax url where you are posting the data will be http://www.example.com/localhost/PHP_scripts/mailinglist.php

Comment: Thank you firebug has confirmed the now correct posting and html response from the PHP script base don Gabe's revision

Comment: @Gabe It did thank you. However now if the email entered doesn't pass, the form that gets sent back (identical to the original in terms of classes and ID's relevant to the click function) no longer has a click function. Do you know why that might be?